# D3.js: Circular clipping path isn't working?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am kind of new to this forum, I use it all the time through google searches which help me a lot, but I stumbled on a pretty unusual problem, I think. I am trying to create a clipping mask from a circle. I pasted the code (edited to be more readable) down here, any help is welcome.

The result should be a grey circle, instead of yellow circle I guess.

```
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circleMale")
        .attr("id", "ellipse-clip")
        .data(exhibits)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")

        //.attr("title", function(d) { return nameFn(d); })
        //.attr("fill", "#CCCCCCC")
        .attr("fill", "#FFFF00")

        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
        .attr("r",100)
        .attr("cx",500)
        .attr("cy",500)
        .attr("opacity", 0.2)

    var clippingPath = svg.append("rect")       
        .attr("x", 125)       
        .attr("y", 75)        
        .attr("clip-path", "url(ellipse-clip)") 
        .style("fill", "lightgrey")   
        .attr("height", 600)    
        .attr("width", 800);
```

Comment: Any comments about some mistakes I made are most welcome aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. a clip-path must point to a [clipPath element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#ClipPathElement), not a circle
2. `url(ellipse-clip)` is incorrect, it should be `url(#ellipse-clip)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! What do you mean by point to an element? I gave my circles an ID named "ellipse-clip", but I guess this aint enough?

Comment: You've skipped over the key word **clipPath** in my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to get what you are saying but it doesnt make sense to me :(, I cant point my clipping path to a circle but its the circle that I want to clip. Where else should I point it?

Comment: to a clipPath element which is the parent of the circle.

Comment: So in this case that would be "svg"?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No, you need to insert a **clipPath** element to be the parent of the circle element. a clip-path can **only** point to a **clipPath** element.

Comment: Think you can show me how to do that based on my code I gave? Code is still some kind of magic to me.